# Tags used in a sequence diagram in an emx file (UML2)

Tags: xml, uml, sequence-diagram

I have an emx file that contains sequence and class diagrams. The diagrams are the result of tracing the execution of a J2EE application.

To maybe help steer you in the right way, I'm trying to convert the sequence diagram to a call graph (of methods). I tried so hard to find documentation that explains all the tags in a sequence diagram (check sample of the emx/xmi code bellow) but i couldn't.

I'm trying to understand the different tags and what they represent in the sequence diagram. For example `<packagedElement xsi:type="uml:Class">` , `<ownedOperation>` , `<packagedElement xsi:type="uml:ReceiveOperationEvent">` ...

Any help is appreciated.

Example of an emx file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
    <uml:Model xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/200`enter code here`1/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML" name="maintrace_main">
      <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:Collaboration" name="Collaboration">
        <ownedBehavior xsi:type="uml:Interaction" name="Interaction">

          <lifeline represents="//Collaboration/@ownedAttribute.0" coveredBy="//Collaboration/Interaction/doGetstart3 //Collaboration/Interaction/doGetend4 //Collaboration/Interaction/doGet5 //Collaboration/Interaction/printlnstart8 //Collaboration/Interaction/printlnreturnEnd14 
            <fragment xsi:type="uml:MessageOccurrenceSpecification" name="doStartTagend568" covered="//Collaboration/Interaction/@lifeline.8" event="//doStartTag565" message="//Collaboration/Interaction/doStartTag.6"/>
          ....
        </ownedBehavior>
        <ownedAttribute type="//test.MainClass"/>
        <ownedAttribute type="//test.Etudiant"/>
      </packagedElement>
      <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:Class" name="test.MainClass" clientDependency="//@packagedElement.29">
        <ownedOperation name="main">
          <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String%5B%5D"/>
        </ownedOperation>
      </packagedElement>
    <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:SendOperationEvent" name="println139" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.util.tracer.Debug/println"/> 
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:ReceiveOperationEvent" name="println143" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.util.tracer.Debug/println"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:SendOperationEvent" name="println144" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.util.tracer.Debug/println"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:ReceiveOperationEvent" name="processRequest147"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:SendOperationEvent" name="processRequest148"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:ReceiveOperationEvent" name="doEnd151" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.handlers.CartHandler/doEnd"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:SendOperationEvent" name="doEnd152" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.handlers.CartHandler/doEnd"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:ReceiveOperationEvent" name="doEnd156" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.handlers.CartHandler/doEnd"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:SendOperationEvent" name="doEnd157" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.handlers.CartHandler/doEnd"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:ReceiveOperationEvent" name="processRequest160" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.RequestProcessor/processRequest"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:SendOperationEvent" name="processRequest161" operation="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.RequestProcessor/processRequest"/>
  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:Class" name="com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.ScreenFlowManager" clientDependency="//@packagedElement.7007 //@packagedElement.7008 //@packagedElement.7009 //@packagedElement.7010 //@packagedElement.7011">
    <ownedOperation name="getNextScreen">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getURLMapping">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.URLMapping" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getTemplate">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.util.Locale"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//java.lang.String" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getScreens">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.util.Locale"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//java.util.HashMap" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getParameter">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String"/>
      <ownedParameter name="arg2" type="//javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.Parameter" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getScreens">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.util.Locale"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//java.util.HashMap" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getParameter">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String"/>
      <ownedParameter name="arg2" type="//javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.Parameter" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getScreens">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.util.Locale"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//java.util.HashMap" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getParameter">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String"/>
      <ownedParameter name="arg2" type="//javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.Parameter" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getScreens">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.util.Locale"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//java.util.HashMap" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getParameter">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String"/>
      <ownedParameter name="arg2" type="//javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.Parameter" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getScreens">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.util.Locale"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//java.util.HashMap" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    <ownedOperation name="getParameter">
      <ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String"/>
      <ownedParameter name="arg2" type="//javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"/>
      <ownedParameter type="//com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.control.web.Parameter" direction="return"/>
    </ownedOperation>
    </uml:Model>
```

Comment: You'll likely find out that, unless you know anyone from a company that has coded this, you better go and have a beer for good. The OMG specs won't help you out. The best you can do is create little sample XMI exports, make tiny changes and see what difference comes out.

Comment: Actually there is a specification for the xmi format, that contains all the information you need: https://www.omg.org/spec/XMI. Of course it is not easy to read, but together with the UML specification you should be able to make sense of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an emx file that contains sequence and class diagrams.

no, the file contents you show does not contains diagram definitions but classes and collaboration definitions. A diagram is a *picture* representing a part of the model, and the UML diagram interchange is very different.

You have to refer at the [UML documentation](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) for more details, but it is easy to guess

- a `<packagedElement xsi:type="uml:Class" ...>` ... `</packagedElement>` defines a class
- a `<ownedOperation name="getURLMapping">` ... `</ownedOperation>` defines the operation *getURLMapping* (here of the class *ScreenFlowManager*)
- `<ownedParameter name="arg1" type="//java.lang.String"/>` indicates the first parameter of the operation *getURLMapping* is named *arg1* and is a Java String
- etc

The definition of a *Collaboration* is more complicated and you truncated it a lot but it is possible to see *lifeline* and some exchanged messages.

Comment: i have deleted the first section of the file. so, am i working with the wrong data ? because i ignored the first half of the file thinking that is not the sequence diagram.
first section contains : <fragment> and <message>

Comment: @MadMaxtun this is the right data, I just rectified about the terminology, lot of people confuse _class_ with _class diagram_ etc. A _sequence diagram_ is a graphical representation of a _collaboration_

Comment: xsi:type=uml:SendOperationEvent then xsi:type="uml:ReceiveOperationEvent" , that is obvious (from --> to) but the problem is that sometimes i find uml:sendoperation , then uml:Class (with a lot of methods as ownedOperation) then uml:ReceiveOperationEvent. i can't really tell how that is represented in the sequence diagram

Comment: typically a sequence diagram (e.g. a collaboration) contains exchanges between instances of classes, and these exchanges can represent the call of operations of the classes typing the instances. XMI is very verbose and the collaborations are not the simplest elements of a model ;-)

Comment: Aw i see , i have uml:Collaboration , but inside of it there are some data that i couldn't figure out like the @ownedAttribute.0 bellow.  <packagedElement xsi:type="uml:Collaboration" name="Collaboration">
    <ownedBehavior xsi:type="uml:Interaction" name="Interaction">
      <lifeline represents="//Collaboration/@ownedAttribute.0" coveredBy="//Collaboration/Interaction/doGetstart3 //Collaboration/Interaction/doGetend4

Comment: @MadMaxtun yes a collaboration is composed of interaction, with lifeline etc, you have to refer to UML terminology and meta model to understand. You can also make some sequence diagrams by yourself then generate the XMI of the supporting collaboration and look at

Comment: @MadMaxtun I let you, it is almost 1am in France, time to sleep ;-)

Comment: i will look into it and get back to you ! bonne nuit et merci !